# Have and have got in BrE

Tags: british-english

Do you (British people) use both "have" and "have got" in BrE?

Ex.
A. I have a.. & I have to..
B. I don't have a.. & I do not have to..
C. Do I have a..? & Do I have to..?

The examples of *have got*:
A. I have got a.. & I have got to..
B. I haven't got a.. & I haven't got to..
C. Have I got a..? & Have I got to..?

Or, do you (BrE) use *have got* in progressive form?

Ex:
I am *having got (having) a.. And I am having to..* (having got)
I am not having got (having) a.. And I am not having to.. (having got)
Am I having got (having) a..? And I am having got (having) to?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both British people and all other native speakers of English use the form have got.

Why?

It's very simple.

**The verb *have* meaning to possess or have in one's possession has two forms in the present simple tense.**

> He has a car.
>
> Question form: Does he have a car? and Has he got a car?
>
> Also, to **have to do something** (obligation): He has to do the work.
>
> Does he have to do the work? Has he got to do the work?
>
> There is no such thing as using **have got** in the progressive tense. "have got" is a form of the verb **have** and it is not a verb (bare infinitive) in its own right.

There is only using the verb ***have*** in the progressive tense in terms of have to do something.

The progressive tense is:

He's having to do the work now. [have to do something]

The bare infinitive of ***have*** meaning possess does not use a continuous tense with that meaning. (We don't say: "He's having a car today." generally speaking, unless it means something slightly different. "He's having a car today instead of taking the bus." There having a car means someone got him a car with a driver, for example.]

You either  **have** or **don't have** or h**aven't got** a car. ***Have*** is not an action verb.

Naturally, that is NOT: to have tea or lunch where have functions like an action verb.

> We're having lunch at noon.

There are other idioms as well: We're having a ball. [meaning:having fun]

Please note: the Brits don't use gotten. Therefore, in British English only, **have got** *can be present perfect or present tense.*